# How to solve "Nothing found" errors on wordpress after upgrading vps then downgrading to shared?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have recently upgraded my website to vps hosting and then downgraded to shared hosting again. After that strange things starts to happen: I get "Nothing found" error on wordpress time to time (Not happening all the time, but sometimes and for some visitors, some pages and frontpage, when I refresh the site comes but another time it shows nothing found..). This also happens to some site visitors.
I believe something wrong with htaccess file or its ignoring by the server. Asked it to hosting support. But nothing helped me.

I have also checked permalinks and re-saved them on wordpress end.

Deleted htaccess file. Still nothing changed. Changed content on htaccess file still nothing has changed. Reuploaded htaccess and still nothing changed.

[SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoMV9.png)

Tried to find httpd.conf (For searching this line: `AllowOverride None`) file but there is no file on my shared server.

I want to do this: Command : sudo a2enmod rewrite but since its a shared server they dont allow me (godaddy). Please help me.

Comment: If it works sometimes, it's probably not an issue with mod_rewrite. Do you use any caching? Do you see the 404 requests in your acces log?

Comment: Yes using cloudflare plugin and nameservers. And yes I saw 404 on log: 49.32.111.94 - - [30/Oct/2017:04:37:55 -0700] "GET /premium-membership/ HTTP/1.1" 404 857 "http://videos.vintagepornbay.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.0.2; en-US; SM-G530H Build/LRX22G) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 UCBrowser/11.0.8.855 U3/0.8.0 Mobile Safari/534.30"
49.32.111.94 - - [30/Oct/2017:04:37:56 -0700] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 857 "http://www.vintagepornbay.com/premium-membership/"   And also I got negative feedback from some of the visitors about this nothing found issue.

Comment: You have some paywall plugin, and it is misbehaving, possibly because of some configuration issue. I'd talk to their support, investigating this yourself isn't going to be easy if you're not coming from a PHP/WP background.

Comment: No I dont think so because before the migration it was all fine (except high i/o , ram usages)

Comment: Well, your 404 is generated by WordPress, so it's either something in your database / config / Plugin or it's a major bug in CloudFlare / GoDaddy. I find the latter less likely, but that's just me.

Comment: Tried disabling cloudflare and its not about cloudflare. I had blocked one country via my htaccess file before. It was showing "forbidden error" to that country visitors before. But now it shows not found error.

Comment: Strange things happening when I disable some plugins it automatically enables after that..